# Firebird ODBC driver data truncated while running select statement

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, odbc, firebird

My select statement looks like this

```
SELECT tb1.name FROM table1 tb1, table2 tb2 WHERE tb2.name=? AND tb2.tb1_key_id=tb1.id;
```

My Bindparameter call looks like this

```
SQLBindParameter(m_hStatement,1,SQL_PARAM_INPUT,SQL_C_CHAR,SQL_CHAR,len,0,(LPVOID)buff,len,(SQLLEN *)pcbValue);
```

where `buff is void*`

When I run SQLExecute on this statement it returning with `SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO` when I look into error details it says `[Firebird ODBC driver] data truncated`.

I am completely new to databases, please let me know if any more details needed

BTW the same stament was working fine with 32 bit application, and getting this issue if compile in 64 bit.

`UPDATE`- Back again to this issue.

I got SQL Trace file

```
MyApp    4e0-1680   ENTER SQLPrepareW 
    HSTMT               0x0000000008C9E210
    WCHAR *             0x000000000DF04CE0 [      -3] "SELECT tb1.name FROM table1 tb1, table2 tb2 WHERE tb2.name=? AND tb2.tb1_key_id=tb1.id;\ 0"
    SDWORD                    -3

MyApp    4e0-1680   EXIT  SQLPrepareW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
    HSTMT               0x0000000008C9E210
    WCHAR *             0x000000000DF04CE0 [      -3] "SELECT tb1.name FROM table1 tb1, table2 tb2 WHERE tb2.name=? AND tb2.tb1_key_id=tb1.id;\ 0"
    SDWORD                    -3

MyApp    4e0-1680   ENTER SQLBindParameter 
    HSTMT               0x0000000008C9E210
    UWORD                        1 
    SWORD                        1 <SQL_PARAM_INPUT>
    SWORD                        1 <SQL_C_CHAR>
    SWORD                        1 <SQL_CHAR>
    SQLULEN                   48
    SWORD                        0 
    PTR                0x0000000008B932D0
    SQLLEN                    48
    SQLLEN *            0x0000000008B93008

MyApp    4e0-1680   EXIT  SQLBindParameter  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
    HSTMT               0x0000000008C9E210
    UWORD                        1 
    SWORD                        1 <SQL_PARAM_INPUT>
    SWORD                        1 <SQL_C_CHAR>
    SWORD                        1 <SQL_CHAR>
    SQLULEN                   48
    SWORD                        0 
    PTR                0x0000000008B932D0
    SQLLEN                    48
    SQLLEN *            0x0000000008B93008 (4294967293)

MyApp    4e0-1680   ENTER SQLBindParameter 
    HSTMT               0x0000000008C9E210
    UWORD                        2 
    SWORD                        1 <SQL_PARAM_INPUT>
    SWORD                        1 <SQL_C_CHAR>
    SWORD                        1 <SQL_CHAR>
    SQLULEN                   48
    SWORD                        0 
    PTR                0x0000000008B93298
    SQLLEN                    48
    SQLLEN *            0x0000000008B93008

MyApp    4e0-1680   EXIT  SQLBindParameter  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
    HSTMT               0x0000000008C9E210
    UWORD                        2 
    SWORD                        1 <SQL_PARAM_INPUT>
    SWORD                        1 <SQL_C_CHAR>
    SWORD                        1 <SQL_CHAR>
    SQLULEN                   48
    SWORD                        0 
    PTR                0x0000000008B93298
    SQLLEN                    48
    SQLLEN *            0x0000000008B93008 (4294967293)

MyApp    4e0-1680   ENTER SQLExecute 
    HSTMT               0x0000000008C9E210

MyApp    4e0-1680   EXIT  SQLExecute  with return code 1 (SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
    HSTMT               0x0000000008C9E210

    DIAG [01004] [ODBC Firebird Driver]Data truncated (0) 

    DIAG [01004] [ODBC Firebird Driver]Data truncated (0) 

MyApp    4e0-1680   ENTER SQLErrorW 
    HENV                0x0000000000000000
    HDBC                0x0000000000000000
    HSTMT               0x0000000008C9E210
    WCHAR *             0x000000000A69BFE8
    SDWORD *            0x000000000A69BFD4
    WCHAR *             0x0000000000123CF0 
    SWORD                     1024 
    SWORD *             0x0000000000124104

MyApp    4e0-1680   EXIT  SQLErrorW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
    HENV                0x0000000000000000
    HDBC                0x0000000000000000
    HSTMT               0x0000000008C9E210
    WCHAR *             0x000000000A69BFE8 [       5] "01004"
    SDWORD *            0x000000000A69BFD4 (0)
    WCHAR *             0x0000000000123CF0 [      36] "[ODBC Firebird Driver]Data truncated"
    SWORD                     1024 
    SWORD *             0x0000000000124104 (36)

MyApp    4e0-1680   ENTER SQLRowCount 
    HSTMT               0x0000000008C9E210
    SQLLEN *            0x0000000000123218

MyApp    4e0-1680   EXIT  SQLRowCount  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
    HSTMT               0x0000000008C9E210
    SQLLEN *            0x0000000000123218 (-1)

MyApp    4e0-1680   ENTER SQLNumResultCols 
    HSTMT               0x0000000008C9E210
    SWORD *             0x00000000001231F4

MyApp    4e0-1680   EXIT  SQLNumResultCols  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
    HSTMT               0x0000000008C9E210
    SWORD *             0x00000000001231F4 (1)

MyApp    4e0-1680   ENTER SQLNumParams 
    HSTMT               0x0000000008C9E210
    SWORD *             0x00000000001231F4

MyApp    4e0-1680   EXIT  SQLNumParams  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
    HSTMT               0x0000000008C9E210
    SWORD *             0x00000000001231F4 (2)
```

Is there anything I can provide for you to help me with this

Comment: If you can't get an answer here, try the Firebird ODBC list, see http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/mailing-lists/ for details. This error can btw happen if your parameter is longer than the declared length of the field.

Answer (score 0):

I usually get weird data truncated issues in Java when my SQL Parameter data cant figure out the type of data im sending it.  Its all a bit hidden under a few layers of abstraction, but generally ive fixed it by escaping my input manually.

Ex.

```
select name from company where name = $P!{input}
```

Will sometimes cause the SQL Exception 'data truncated'

```
select name from company where name = '$P!{input}'
```

Where the $P!{ means put the data straight into the string.  Give that a shot?  Maybe theres a type inference issue going on.